# scrapy parametrizar el paso de reglas a la clase

Tags: python, scrapy

Estoy desarrollando un proceso, que lee desde una base de datos, cierta informacion (que viene de otro sistema), y que contiene los parametros para realizar un proceso de webscraping sobre una URL en particular.
Los parametros son (entre varios)

- URL: sitio web a escanear \
- LinkExtractorH: Clave para recorrer horizontalmente
- LinkExtractorV: clave para recorrer verticalmente

por otro lado, tengo el siguiente script realizado con scrapy:

```
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class Articulo(Item):
    titulo = Field()
    contenido = Field()

class ProcesoSpyder(CrawlSpider):

    def __init__(self, args):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self, self.name)
        self.start_urls                 = args[0]
        self.allowed_domain             = args[1]
        self.download_delay             = args[2]
        self.custom_settings            = args[3]
        self.rules                      = args[4]

    name = "miScraper"

    def parse_items(self, response):
        item = ItemLoader(Articulo(), response)
        item.add_xpath('titulo', '//td[@class="titulonoti"]/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').strip()))
        item.add_xpath('contenido', '//div[@class="ui-pdp-description"]/p/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').strip()))
        yield item.load_item()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'datos.json'
    })
    
    # parametros
    START_URLs              = 'http://www.gorevalparaiso.cl/noticias.php'
    ALLOWED_DOMAINs         = 'gorevalparaiso.cl'
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY          = 2

    RULES = (
        Rule( LinkExtractor(allow=r'/?pag=\d+'),  follow=True), # REGLA #1 => HORIZONTALIDAD POR PAGINACION
        Rule( LinkExtractor(allow=r'/?id=\d+'),  follow=True,   # REGLA #2 => VERTICALIDAD AL DETALLE DE LOS ARTICULOS
                            callback='parse_items'), 
    )

    CUSTOM_SETTINGS = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36',
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20 
    }

    process.crawl(ProcesoSpyder, [  [START_URLs],
                                    [ALLOWED_DOMAINs],
                                    DOWNLOAD_DELAY,
                                    CUSTOM_SETTINGS,
                                    RULES
                                ])
    process.start()
```

Tal y como se puede apreciar, en el codigo estoy pasando como parametros varios parametros a la clase, los cuales son pasados correctamente.
de todos los parametros pasados a la clase, el unico que no esta funcionando, es el que se indica como RULES (quinto parametro)
Al establecer el valor en el init de la clase, me cancela el proceso de scrap.

Aca dejo la salida que me esta generando la ejecucion del proceso

```
python3 ejecutar.py 
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.7.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.14, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0], pyOpenSSL 23.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022), cryptography 39.0.0, Platform Linux-5.15.0-58-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{}
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/desa/Simone/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/request.py:231: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
  return cls(crawler)

2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 6a3971a2424d90da
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/desa/Simone/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py:289: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: The `FEED_URI` and `FEED_FORMAT` settings have been deprecated in favor of the `FEEDS` setting. Please see the `FEEDS` setting docs for more details
  exporter = cls(crawler)

2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
ESTAS SON LAS RULES
(<scrapy.spiders.crawl.Rule object at 0x7f8efc017520>, <scrapy.spiders.crawl.Rule object at 0x7f8efc0170a0>)
*******************
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-02-01 16:55:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.gorevalparaiso.cl/noticias.php> (referer: None)
2023-02-01 16:55:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-02-01 16:55:11 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 233,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5229,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.246428,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 19, 55, 11, 61215),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 20828,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'memusage/max': 62459904,
 'memusage/startup': 62459904,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 1, 19, 55, 10, 814787)}
2023-02-01 16:55:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Como se puede apreciar, la ejecucion no genera ningun error.

Hasta el momento, tengo la sospecha de que el error puede ser en el paso del partametro RULES, a la clase ProcesoSpyder.

Necesito hacer esto, para poder automatizar el scrap entre varias URLs de forma automatica cada cierta cantidad de dias, por lo cual no existe posibilidad de que un usuario ejecute el proceso de forma manual en una consola.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

por alguna razon tampoco me funciono la rules en el contructor por lo que le deje aparte del contructor
[image: codigo]

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/402142)